# Java won't run in VSCode - imports not functioning

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Ok, so I followed the guide on vscode website to the T, and I'm stuck where it says the debugger will create the launch.json for me. There is no launch.json.

Here's the guide for your ref - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial

When I run the code it tells me that none of the packages/methods are defined. Specifically that anything outside of that single file is undefined. any imports don't work at all; Although all the packages/methods are there and included in the program.

main.java:2: error: package exceptions does not exist
import exceptions.myException;

Even the pre-built program I cloned from github doesn't work.

I've installed the java extensions pack which includes Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat and Debugger for Java.

I have JDK installed and the path is defined in my environment variables as JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161.

I've also installed maven and checked to make the version checked out through the CMD prompt.

I've watched around 10 yt vids and they all say the same thing.

if anyone has a decent guide on how to set this up or can personally walk me through the process I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you see the thumbsup icon when a .java file is open as decribed in https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/#troubleshooting